# Querying a Parent object based on a Child M2M's own M2M relationship

Tags: python, django

I have two types of objects, one is a parent and one is a child:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    children = models.ManyToMany(Child)

class Child(models.Model):
    compatable_children = models.ManyToMany("self")
```

I use the Parent object to display in my application, but I need to filter it based on the existence of a child within the compatable_children field.

So something like:

```
filter_child = Child.objects.filter(id=blah)
queryset = Parent.objects.filter(children__compatable_children__contains=filter_child)
```

How can I achieve something like this query?

Comment: ```queryset = Parent.objects.filter(children__compatable_children__id=blah)``` maybe works

Comment: What is wrong with that query?